# Start download from servlet via gwt (http get)

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, get, httprequest

I would like to start a file download from a clickevent in my gwt web app. So I wrote a Servlet which writes the data to the output and should start the download. The data is received via http get.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String data = request.getParameter("data");
    String filename = request.getParameter("filename");
    byte[] streamData = data.getBytes();
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; fileName="
            + filename + ".csv");
    response.setContentLength(streamData.length);

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(streamData);
    out.flush();
}
```

In the client I start the get method via requestBuilder.sendRequest():

```
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, /download");
requestBuilder.sendRequest("filename=dues&data="+ theDataAsString, new RequestCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponseReceived(Request request,
                            Response response) {
                        // Anything to do here?
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                        SC.warn("Error while creating export file.");
                    }
                });
```

Nothing happens. But why? Shouldn't the browser ask to begin a download?

Does it, in this case, matter if i use post or get?

I don't want to use somthing like

```
Window.open("/download?data=myData&filename=filename", "_blank", "");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The servlet does nothing than returning the retrieved request parameter back in the response body (possibly with the wrong character encoding). What's the whole purpose of the servlet here then? I don't do GWT, but why don't you just write that to its response directly?

Comment: @BalusC: The problem ist that all the GWT Java code is translated into JavaScript and there is no support for `java.io.*`, so I have to work with a Servlet. But you were right with the encoding, in my case I should use "text/csv". (But actually "application/force-download" does work as well)

Comment: Re GWT: Okay. Re encoding: No, I meant the character encoding as you would need to specify in `String#getBytes()` and `HttpServletResponse#setCharacterEncoding()`. Not specifying the character encoding would result in the platform default one being used which may malform the characters if they are not originally encoded using the same encoding.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. But I didn't get it yet: Will the encoding result in the default of the Servlet platform? Or will it be the encoding of the sending client (my  smartgwt client)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side, use an Anchor instead of a request builder and invoke the servlet directly.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I don't know why `requestBuilder.sendRequest()` did not work but Anchor does. Actually I now use post method and a FormPanel instead of Anchor...